# Can't create rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress

I try to create rewrite rule for my custom post type. I need it to be something like "/%post_type_name%/%taxonomy_slug/%post_slug%". Here's the code I used to add rule:

```
add_action('init', 'episodes_rewrites_init');

function episodes_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^episodes/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=episodes&seasons=$matches[1]&episodes=$matches[2]', 'top'
    );
}
```

It doesn't work and i can't figure out why. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just installed plugin called "Custom Post Type Permalinks", added url template for my custom post like "/%seasons%/%postname%/" and now it rewrites urls like I want. But I still don't know how to do it in code though...

Answer (score 0):

Well mate, I have never used `add_rewrite_rule`, WP codex says that is `It is most commonly used in conjunction with add_rewrite_tag()`.
So just I show you how veterans used to do this rewriting rules in the old times.
But moreover If you are building a plugin for the masses you must avoid use `WP 3.5 features` Much people still use WP2.*.

These set of actions can help you:

```
add_action('init', 'flushRewriteRules');
function flushRewriteRules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'insertMyRewriteRules');
function insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules['^episodes/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=episodes&seasons=$matches[1]&episodes=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'insertMyRewriteQueryVars');
function insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'episodes', 'seasons', 'post_type');
    return $vars;
}
```